# Jackson - Populate Nested Parent Id

Tags: jackson, deserialization

I have the following Json file:

```
{
    "workflowId": "1",
    "cpoWorkflowSteps": [
        {
            "workflowStepId": "1",
            "workflowStepName": "START",
            "workflowStepDescription": "Start Step responsable to transfer file one",
            "cpoWorkflowStepControlsForWorkflowStepId": [
                {
                    "workflowStepControlId": "1",
                    "cpoWorkflowStepByWorkflowNextStepId": {
                        "workflowStepId": "2",
                        "workflowStepName": "STEP_2",
                        "workflowStepDescription": "Middle Step responsable to transfer file one",
                        "cpoWorkflowStepControlsForWorkflowStepId": [
                            {
                                "workflowStepControlId": "2",
                                "cpoWorkflowStepByWorkflowNextStepId": {
                                    "workflowStepId": "3",
                                    "workflowStepName": "STEP_3",
                                    "workflowStepDescription": "Middle Step responsable to transfer file one",
                                    "cpoWorkflowStepControlsForWorkflowStepId": [
                                        {
                                            "workflowStepControlId": "7",
                                            "cpoWorkflowStepByWorkflowNextStepId": {
                                                "workflowStepId": "6",
                                                "workflowStepName": "STEP_6",
                                                "workflowStepDescription": "End Step responsable to transfer file one",
```

To populate the child id with the parent id I do the following:

```
workflow.getCpoWorkflowSteps()
       .forEach(cpoWorkStep -> cpoWorkStep.getCpoWorkflowStepControlsForWorkflowStepId()
            .forEach(cpoStepControl -> cpoStepControl.setCpoWorkflowStepByWorkflowStepId(cpoWorkStep)));
```

But how can I populate the next child id with the parent id considering I don't know where is the end of this nested objects?

**EDIT: How can I call accept method recursively to populate the next object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create a method to call recursively to populate the next child object with the parent Id:

```
private void setCpoWorkflowStepParentId(CpoWorkflowStep cpoWorkflowStep) {
        List<CpoWorkflowStepControl> list = cpoWorkflowStep.getCpoWorkflowStepControlsForWorkflowStepId().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (CpoWorkflowStepControl cpoWorkflowStepControl : list) {
            cpoWorkflowStepControl.setCpoWorkflowStepByWorkflowStepId(cpoWorkflowStep);
            if(cpoWorkflowStepControl.getCpoWorkflowStepByWorkflowNextStepId() != null) {
                //Call recursively to populate the next CpoWorkflowStep child with the parent id
                this.setCpoWorkflowStepParentId(cpoWorkflowStepControl.getCpoWorkflowStepByWorkflowNextStepId());
            }

        }
    }
```

And to call this method:

```
workflow.getCpoWorkflowSteps().forEach(
                    cpoWorkStep -> this.setCpoWorkflowStepParentId(cpoWorkStep));
```